# A filter with objectId is not performed at the database level

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark

I am occupying the mongo connector (`mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.3.1`), when I make a query about the primary key that is of type ObjectId. It never does Pushed to DB

**example (ObjectId) :**

|-- _id: struct (nullable = true)
  |       |-- oid: string (nullable = true)

`dataframe1.filter($"_id.oid" === ("58115596d12d37d780353ed7"))`

`== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Filter ((_id#491.oid = 58115596d12d37d780353ed7) && isnotnull(_id#491))
+- *(1) Scan MongoRelation(MongoRDD[73] at RDD ... PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(_id)] ...`

, but if it is of another type it does.

**example (String):**

**_id: string (nullable = true)**

`dataframe2.filter($"_id" === ("LEM"))`

`== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Filter (isnotnull(_id#455) && (_id#455 = LEM))
+- *(1) Scan MongoRelation(MongoRDD[52] at RDD at ...... PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(_id), EqualTo(_id,LEM)] ..`

Does anyone know any way to perform these queries at the database level with spark and mongodb?